# How to work out coin toss/dice roll probabilities without using tree diagrams

Tags: probability

Working through the probability section in grade 7 khan academy and, while using tree diagrams to work out the probability of getting at least two heads with three flips of a fair coin is easy, it's also tedious. I'm convinced that there must be a more elegant way of finding out the correct probability, but I do not know what it is!

Here's a link to the problem page: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/cc-seventh-grade-math/cc-7th-probability-statistics/cc-7th-compound-events/e/compound-events (note: some of the questions in the exercise do not relate to this question. Obviously the chances of a getting a tails, heads, and heads are 1/8. You don't even need a tree diagram for that one)

Comment: Look  at Wikipedia, binomial distribution.

Comment: For this problem, note that we are sure to get at least two heads or at least two tails, and we cannot have at least two of each. By symmetry the probability of at least two heads is the same as the probability of at least two tails. So each has probability $1/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The probability of getting at least two heads with three flips of a fair coin.

Yes, there is some counting involved. This is well studied and called a [binomial distrubtion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).
Essentially, if you have $n$ independent trials with probability $p$ of success, then the probability of exactly $k$ successes is
$$\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k},$$
where 
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!},$$
and the `!` is the [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).

So, one way to get the probability you want is 
to recognize we have $n=3$ independent trials (flips) with probability $p = 1/2$ of success (heads). To get at least two heads is the same event as get exactly 2 heads or exactly 3 heads. Let $A = \{\text{Get exactly 2 heads}\}$ and $B = \{\text{Get exactly 3 heads}\}$. Then using [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), we are interested in
$$P(A\text{ or } B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\text{ and } B).$$
Since you cannot exactly 2 ($A$) **and** exactly 3 ($B$) heads in three flips, then the $P(A\text{ and } B) = 0$, and so
$$P(A\text{ or B}) = P(A)+P(B) -0= \binom{3}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^1+\binom{3}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^0 = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Please forgive my very basic understanding of maths. Just need to clarify. I understand that n = 3, and p = 1/2, I lose you a bit when it comes to adding the probabilities. If it's not too much trouble, could you explain in more detail the (3/2) (1/2)^2 (1/2)^1 + (3/2) (1/2)^3 (1/2)^0?

Comment: @OwenAlexander Yeah, I thought that might be an issue. I did want to introduce too much notation since I don't how much you would understand. Have a look now, and let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: This is how my primitive brain is interpreting this: the (3 2) and (3 3) notation is unfamiliar to me. I'm assuming it's designating a set of probabilities? The first being all the A probabilities and the second (3 3) being all the B probabilities? So I don't include those numbers in my calculation. I then find the (1/2)^2 and multiply that by (1/2)^1 and add this to (1/2)^3 times (1/2)^0. This gives me 1/4*1/2 + 1/8*1/2. I get 3/16... which is wrong. Where have I gone wrong? (really appreciate the help)

Comment: ...sorry (1/2)^0 is 1 so the answer I get is 2/8

Comment: @OwenAlexander In the middle of my explanation, you will see that $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$. This is a counting factor. In the first case, we need to count how many ways we can have exactly 2 $H$ in three flips. There are only 3 ways: $HHT, HTH, THH$. So, if you calculate it, you will see that $\binom{3}{2} = 3$. Similarly there is only one way to get 3 $H$ out of three flips $HHH$, So, $\binom{3}{3} = 1.$ Now try again.

Comment: ha, ok I got 4/8 this time. One final question. So do you have to manually count the possibilities? I guess my original question was whether or not you could bypass the counting side of things. When it's a couple of coin flips, counting is ok. But what if you were dealing with 4567 coin flips?

Comment: @OwenAlexander I forgot to mention, $\binom{n}{k}$ is the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). $\binom{3}{2} = \frac{3!}{2!(3-2)!} = \frac{3\cdot2\cdot1}{2\cdot1\cdot1} = 3$, so no you don't have to manually count, but you have to at least calculate the binomial coefficient. As convention, $0! = 1$.

Comment: Ah ok. Time I turned my attention to binomial coefficients! Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: @OwenAlexander Ok, no problem. Good luck.